# duplicate connection on socket.io. status pending xhr

Tags: javascript, cordova, sockets, ionic-framework, websocket

I have a problem with socket.io client in ionic. iam using it in a cordova android . Sometimes it duplicates the connection or at least I interpret it, and when ocurrs the connection status (pending) appears I can not logging in to the application.

This error happens sometimes. If that does not appear pending status , the application allows me to log correctly.

After a minute I get the pending connection as an error 400 bad request and there if I can login correctly in the application.

```
(function () {

    angular.module('starter')
        .service('SocketService', ['socketFactory', SocketService]);


    function SocketService(socketFactory) {

        console.log("conectando con el server");
        return socketFactory({

            ioSocket: io.connect('http://54.221.207.114:3001')


        });
    }
})();
```

[image]

Comment: I think that is not an issue of socket.io, it is more a problem how you call the function. I think, you call it twice. For testing set a flag, so it is called once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ioSocket: io.connect('http://54.221.207.114:3001', {'transports': ['websocket']})

with "'transports':websocket" it works